# class member shared between instance copies

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a class with a member shared by some instances (by copies of the first instance), something like `std::shared_ptr`.

The member is small (`int`) so `std::shared_ptr` and memory allocation look like overkill.

Additional requirements are: it must be possible to work with raw value and address as with ordinal `int`.

Is this possible without `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: On the other hand, implementing your own may be "overkill" when you have `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to some casts, and performance is definitely a concern, you could do something like this:

```cpp
class Object {
    bool original; // True if "original" object, false if copy.
    intptr_t value;

public:
    Object(int val) : original(true), value(val) {}
    Object(const Object& other) : original(false), 
                                  value(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&other.value));

    intptr_t getValue() const {
        return original ? value : *reinterpret_cast<intptr_t*>(value);
    }
};
```

Avoids dynamic allocation, doesn't use a lot of memory, but does some pointer casts so obviously be careful. And of course this depends on `intptr_t` support, which is optional for standard library implementations.

std::shared_ptr is definitely the more reliable way of going about this, so if performance is not a critical issue or you're using larger types, please do consider using it instead.

Comment: Fails poorly if the original object's lifetime ends.

Comment: True, and this answer is already contingent on a number of different things. My intent was mainly just to show *some* alternative to shared_ptr, if it's really desirable to avoid it. You're not going to get lifetime-independent functionality without some kind of dynamic allocation.